# Load native C modules in duktape 2.1.0 to

Tags: javascript, node.js, duktape

I am still lost after reading the how-to article.

- https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/tree/master/extras/module-node

It is said that

> The load callback is a Duktape/C function which takes the resolved module ID and: (1) returns the Ecmascript source code for the module or undefined if there's no source code, e.g. for pure C modules, (2) can populate module.exports itself, and (3) can replace module.exports.

But when loading a native C module,

- what should be pushed into the value stack? `duk_push_undefined(ctx)` instead of `duk_push_string(ctx, module_source)`?
- what should be returned by the load callback to its caller? `return 0` instead of `return 1`?

I tried to call `myobject_init` (using the default instance in http://wiki.duktape.org/HowtoNativeConstructor.html) in the load callback `cb_load_module`. But duktape complains

> TypeError: [object Object] not constructable

when I evaluate `var MyObject = require("MyObject")`, no matter if I

- push undefined into the value stack and return 1,
- or push nothing into the value stack and return 0.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.
There are a few more details scattered in

- https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/blob/master/doc/c-module-convention.rst
- http://wiki.duktape.org/HowtoModules.html It is about duktape 1.x module loading framework, but it helps understanding 2.x framework.

The most important tricks are:

- The module init function should return a function (constructor is also a function). Do NOT register the function using `duk_put_global_string`.

  ```
  duk_ret_t module_init(duk_context* ctx)
  {
      duk_push_c_function(ctx, module_constructor, num_arguments_for_constructor);
      // set properties for the constructor
      return 1;    // stack: [ ... constructor ]
  }
  ```
- The function `cb_load_module` must push the module init function into the value stack, then use `duk_call` to call it and set `module.exports`. Do NOT call the module init function directly.

  ```
  duk_ret_t cb_load_module(duk_context *ctx)
  {
      // stack: [ resolved_id exports module ]
      ...
      duk_push_c_function(ctx, module_init, 0);
      duk_call(ctx, 0);
      duk_put_prop_string(ctx, 2, "exports");  // obj_idx(module) = 2
      return 0;  // no .js source for native modules
  }
  ```